# Using threads in java how can i implement this petri net?

Tags: java, multithreading, petri-net

[image: the petri net]
So, i have to implement some petri nets in java and I have to use threads. The Synchronized method is pretty clear when i have to use it just once. The wait/notify method is't really clear for me, so i'm stuck. If anyone could explain it to me how should i do this it would be a really big help.

Comment: wait/notify is pretty low-level. You might find it more pleasant to work with [ReentrantLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html) and [Condition](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html).

Comment: @dnault  ReentrantLock and Condition are even lower.